# Why do I not get an compiler error here

Tags: java

With the code below I get a NullPointerException at runtime. Why don't I get a compiler error here?

```
public class NullPointerExceptionDemo {     
    int x = 12;     

    static NullPointerExceptionDemo reset(NullPointerExceptionDemo obj) {
        obj = null;     
        return obj;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        NullPointerExceptionDemo o1 = new NullPointerExceptionDemo(); 
        o1 = reset(o1); 
        System.out.print(o1.x); 
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line you think of Compilation error?

Comment: Because that's perfectly valid code?

Comment: Ankit,  System.out.print(o1.x); // At this line u r calling the variable with null object. So i think at this line it should give compilation error. I saw many other places also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation error is a state, when compiler fails to compile the source code, it means, that code contains for example some syntax error. Your code is correct from syntax point of view. So, this is the reason. NPE will be thrown during program run, because `o1` is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

This will not cause compilation error. It will throw NPE in runtime from `o1.x` since `o1` is null. There is no problem in code to thrown compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

No compilation error. It will throw RunTimeException. Because o1 is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have set null  obj = null; by calling reset method and then printing object so it is throwing NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Its is just an outpout of your code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.pack.NullPointerExceptionDemo.main(NullPointerExceptionDemo.java:13)
```

If you are getting output like above. It is not an exception.